# What are objective c exceptions useful for?

Tags: objective-c, exception

I've read many articles about Objective-C exceptions, and I can't figure out what they are useful for.
They're use is discouraged when the error is recoverable (because of many leak-related issues). This reads: use them wherever you would use exit(0) (or similar construct). This also reads: use them whenever you do not expect them to be @catch-ed.

Am I missing something, or are they just a feature to be completely avoided?

Comment: What memory issues, care to share a link?

Answer (score 3):

This is from Apple's *The Objective-C Programming Language* ebook:

> "Important: In many environments, use of exceptions is fairly
>   commonplace. For example, you might throw an exception to signal that
>   a routine could not execute normally—such as when a file is missing or
>   data could not be parsed correctly. Exceptions are resource-intensive
>   in Objective-C. You should not use exceptions for general flow-
>   control, or simply to signify errors. Instead you should use the
>   return value of a method or function to indicate that an error has
>   occurred, and provide information about the problem in an error
>   object. For more information, see [Error Handling Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH201-SW1)." (Apple *The Objective-C Programming Language*,Chapter 10, Exception
>   Handling)

As I understand it, programmers coming from certain other languages (Java?) are used to littering their code with exception/try/catch handlers as a means of flow control. This is considered to be *very bad practice* in objective-C as you code will take a heavy performance hit. Apple advise that any exception handling code *should be removed from shipping code*. Any situation that would give rise to an exception will be a *programmer error* giving rise to a crash condition, not a user error. NSError objects are provided for runtime error-handling.

Therefore the only use for exceptions would appear to be as a debugging aid. But I've seen too much bad advice on this from coders coming from certain other environments - so I think yes, best completely avoided.

See also Apple's [note on errors and exceptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW6), and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Articles/ExceptionsAndCocoaFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009045-SW1):

> The Cocoa frameworks are generally not exception-safe. The general pattern is that exceptions are reserved for programmer error only, and the program catching such an exception should quit soon afterwards.

Comment: I knew about all the reasons why NOT to use exceptions, but thanks anyway for the time you took pointing them out. I'm still looking for a reason to use them, but it looks like it doesn't exist (except for debugging aid which IMHO is a very weak reason for such a complex feature). I wonder why apple guys don't just deprecate them.